# Converting CSV files to Excel workbooks

Tags: converting, vba, csv, excel

My converter converts all CSV files in the subfolders of folders 1, 2 & 3 into Excel workbooks. As of now, I am converting using codes for each folders. I previously *tried* to combine those into one using for loop, but an error occurred, so I've rolled back to the **working** code I had before the loop.

Can anyone show me how to clean this up with a loop or another method?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim CSVfolder As String, CSVfolder1 As String, CSVfolder2 As String
 Dim fname, fname1, fname2 As String
 Dim wBook As Workbook
 Dim colSF As Collection
 Dim vFile, vFile1, vFile2
 Dim bHadFiles As Boolean
 CSVfolder = "C:\Charts\1\"
 CSVfolder1 = "C:\Charts\2\"
 CSVfolder2 = "C:\Charts\3\"

 Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVfolder)
 For Each vFile In colSF
 fname = Dir(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv")
 Do While fname <> ""
    bHadFiles = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wBook.Close False
 fname = Dir()
 Loop
 If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv"
 Next

Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVfolder1)
For Each vFile1 In colSF
fname1 = Dir(CSVfolder1 & vFile1 & "\" & "*.csv")
Do While fname1 <> ""
    bHadFiles = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder1 & vFile1 & "\" & fname1, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs CSVFolder1 & vFile1 & "\" & Replace(fname1, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wBook.Close False
fname1 = Dir()
 Loop
 If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVfolder1 & vFile1 & "\" & "*.csv"
 Next

Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVfolder2)
For Each vFile2 In colSF
fname2 = Dir(CSVfolder2 & vFile2 & "\" & "*.csv")
Do While fname2 <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder2 & vFile2 & "\" & fname2, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs CSVFolder2 & vFile2 & "\" & Replace(fname2, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wBook.Close False
 fname2 = Dir()
 Loop
 If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVfolder2 & vFile2 & "\" & "*.csv"
 Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub

Function GetSubFolders(sPath As String) As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection, f
    f = Dir(sPath, vbDirectory + vbNormal)
    Do While f <> ""
        If GetAttr(sPath & f) And vbDirectory Then
            If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then col.Add f
        End If
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set GetSubFolders = col
End Function
```

Comment: I made a pretty significant edit to get this on topic. If you're interested in fixing that particular error in the 2nd piece of code, I recommend stack overflow. However, I think you and this code would benefit from a general review, so I wanted to salvage the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very first thing we need to do is fix the indentation. If we can't read the code, we can't make it better. Everything inside of `Sub...End Sub` should be one level in. Add another level when you enter an `If`, `For`, `For Each`, or `Select`.

```
Sub Foo

    ' some code 

    Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVfolder)
    For Each vFile In colSF
        fname = Dir(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv")
        Do While fname <> ""
            bHadFiles = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
            wBook.SaveAs CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wBook.Close False
            fname = Dir()
        Loop
        If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv"
    Next

    ' more code

End Sub
```

You had the right idea with the loop. A loop will definitely clean this up immensely, but before we get to a loop, first let's extract a method to remove the duplication.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    Dim CSVfolder As String, CSVfolder1 As String, CSVfolder2 As String
    CSVfolder = "C:\Charts\1\"
    CSVfolder1 = "C:\Charts\2\"
    CSVfolder2 = "C:\Charts\3\"

    TransformFile CSVfolder
    TransformFile CSVfolder1
    TransformFile CSVfolder2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub TransformFile(ByVal CSVfolder As String)
    Dim fname As String
    Dim vFile
    Dim colSF As Collection
    Dim wBook As Workbook

    Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVfolder)
    For Each vFile In colSF
        fname = Dir(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv")
        Do While fname <> ""
            bHadFiles = True
            Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
            wBook.SaveAs CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wBook.Close False
            fname = Dir()
        Loop
        If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVfolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv"
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that *all I did* was move the code into it's own method and call it appropriately. There's still no loop, but now moving to a loop is both trivial and almost unnecessary. We like clean code around here though, so let's go ahead and do that.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim folders As New Collection
    folders.Add "1"
    folders.Add "2"
    folders.Add "3"

    'must be a variant in order to loop over a string collection
    'using a string array instead of a collection is another good option
    Dim CSVFolder As Variant 
    For Each CSVFolder In folders
        TransformFile CSVFolder
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I noticed you have this is a code behind, you may want to move this code to it's own module or class and call it from the click handler. That way your logic isn't bound up in the GUI where it can't be re-used. The only other thing to mention here is that if you're turning the screen updating off, then you ***must*** use an error handler to ensure that it always gets turned back on.

But we're not done yet, we extracted that method out, but left our mess hidden away in there. Let's clean it up too.

> ```
> Private Sub TransformFile(ByVal CSVFolder As String)
>     Dim fname As String
>     Dim vFile
>     Dim colSF As Collection
>     Dim wBook As Workbook
>
>     Set colSF = GetSubFolders(CSVFolder)
>     For Each vFile In colSF
>         fname = Dir(CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv")
>         Do While fname <> ""
>             bHadFiles = True
>             Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>             Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
>             wBook.SaveAs CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
>             Application.CutCopyMode = False
>             wBook.Close False
>             fname = Dir()
>         Loop
>         If bHadFiles Then Kill CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv"
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```

How many times do you need to concatenate this path together?

> ```
> CSVFolder & vFile & "\" & "*.csv"
> ```

Yikes! Do it once before you enter the while loop.

```
For Each vFile In colSF

    filePath = CSVFolder & vFile & "\"

    fname = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")
    Do While fname <> ""
        bHadFiles = True
        Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
        wBook.SaveAs filePath & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wBook.Close False
        fname = Dir()
    Loop
    If bHadFiles Then Kill filePath & "*.csv"
Next
```

No offense, but WTF is `colSF`? It's a collection of folder names, right? Then just call it that. While we're at it, burn the hungarian notation. The name `hadFiles` already tells us that it's a boolean. I'm also going to add some vertical white space to group related actions together. Oh, and I'm going to remove `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. I seriously have no idea what it's doing here. It's not doing anything important at least.

```
Private Sub TransformFile(ByVal CSVFolder As String)
    Dim filename As String
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim folderNames As Collection
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim hadFiles As Boolean
    Dim filePath As String

    Set folderNames = GetSubFolders(CSVFolder)
    For Each vFile In folderNames

        filePath = CSVFolder & vFile & "\"

        filename = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")
        Do While filename <> ""
            hadFiles = True

            Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & filename, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
            wBook.SaveAs filePath & Replace(filename, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wBook.Close False

            filename = Dir()
        Loop

        If hadFiles Then Kill filePath & "*.csv"
    Next
End Sub
```

In general, don't oneline `If` statements. It makes them hard to visually parse. This is doubly important on lines of code that *Kill* files.

```
If hadFiles Then 
    Kill filePath & "*.csv"
End If
```

Things are getting better, but there's still a lot of variables. We can remove one by leaning on the face that `colSF` (i.e. `folderNames`) is never used as anything but an iterator.

> ```
>     Set folderNames = GetSubFolders(CSVFolder)
>     For Each vFile In folderNames
> ```

Becomes

```
    For Each vFile In GetSubFolders(CSVFolder)
```

Don't worry about the function getting called repeatedly, it won't. It executes once and then we're iterating over the collection that it returned.

Here's the code I ended up with. It's probably not getting much simpler unless you switch to the more powerful [FileSystemObject in the Scripting Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx). I encourage you to take a look at what's available there and leave it as an exercise for you to implement this using it instead.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const rootFolder As String = "C:\Charts\"

    Dim folders As New Collection
    folders.Add "1"
    folders.Add "2"
    folders.Add "3"

    Dim CSVFolder As Variant 'must be a variant in order to loop over a string collection
    For Each CSVFolder In folders
        TransformFile rootFolder & CSVFolder & "\"
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub TransformFile(ByVal CSVFolder As String)
    Dim filename As String
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim hadFiles As Boolean
    Dim filePath As String

    For Each vFile In GetSubFolders(CSVFolder)

        filePath = CSVFolder & vFile & "\"

        filename = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")
        Do While filename <> ""
            hadFiles = True

            Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & filename, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
            wBook.SaveAs filePath & Replace(filename, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wBook.Close False

            filename = Dir()
        Loop

        If hadFiles Then
            Kill filePath & "*.csv"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Professor Duck! You are awesome!! I am into this excel-vba for last 4-5 weeks. Thanks for valuable advices.

Comment: You're very welcome. I improved your suggested edit. I meant to create a constant for the root directory and had forgotten.

Comment: @RubberDuck - looks like you've forgotten to include the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` line in your final code although it is included in the code further up your answer.

Comment: In the past I had seen somewhere that `Dir` internally caches the path given to it (which is how subsequent calls return the next match) and therefore you should avoid making nested calls to it using different paths. I'm guessing that you encounter no issues with this code?

Comment: Thanks @ChipsLetten. It took a bit to write this. Im away from my machine atm. Would you mind suggesting an edit?

Comment: Can't say I tested it @ChipsLetten, but there shouldn't be any issues. It's getting a fresh file path at the beginning of each do while.

Comment: Edit suggested.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Sorry about that, as a general rule it is not allowed to edit code, but in this case it was fine.  Could you re-suggest the edit?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with everything suggested by @RubberDuck but wanted to show how the code could be written to remove the need for the hard-coded list of subfolders at the very beginning.

> folders.Add "1"
>       folders.Add "2"
>       folders.Add "3"

The existing `GetSubFolders` also doesn't dig into further levels of subfolders and the `Dir` function starts throwing errors if you try to use it recursively.

There is also an argument to be made that `TransformFile` is doing more than one thing because it is finding subfolders *and* transforming the files it finds.

I have changed `GetSubFolders` from a function to a procedure that takes both the starting path and the `Collection` that must get populated. This way the procedure can call itself whenever it finds a subfolder so that it can look within that folder for a further level of subfolders. It also now uses the `FileSystemObject` from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. You will need to set a reference to this library - from the VBA IDE select the Tools -> References menu. Scroll down until you find the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" entry and check the box.

The revised code now populates a collection with all the folders found below the path of the folder passed to it.

```
Private Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef sPath As String, ByRef theFolders As Collection)
    Dim fileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim subFolder As Scripting.Folder

    Set fileSystem = New FileSystemObject

    For Each subFolder In fileSystem.GetFolder(sPath).SubFolders
        theFolders.Add fileSystem.BuildPath(subFolder.Path, "")
        ' Also look for another level of folders
        Call GetSubFolders(subFolder.Path, theFolders)
    Next subFolder
End Sub
```

The main procedure becomes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const rootFolder As String = "C:\Charts\"

    Dim theFolders As New Collection

    Call GetSubFolders(rootFolder, theFolders)

    Dim CSVFolder As Variant 'must be a variant in order to loop over a string collection
    For Each CSVFolder In theFolders
        Call TransformFile (CSVFolder)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And `TransformFile` gets changed as shown below. There is a design-decision as to whether the code should delete each csv file as it loops over them or just delete them all at the end.

```
Private Sub TransformFile(ByVal CSVFolder As String)
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim hadFiles As Boolean
    Dim filePath As String

    If Right(CSVFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        filePath = CSVFolder & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        filePath = CSVFolder
    End If

    filename = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")
    Do While filename <> ""
        hadFiles = True

        Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & filename, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
        wBook.SaveAs filePath & Replace(filename, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wBook.Close False

        ' Maybe we should be deleting the csv file in case we get an error
        ' before we've finished all the files in this folder?
        ' This would be slower though
        'Kill filePath & filename

        filename = Dir()
    Loop

    If hadFiles Then
        Kill filePath & "*.csv"
    End If
End Sub
```

On a side-note, I personally use the `Call` keyword when making a call to a procedure but I have seen statements that it is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: [meta review] Mind if I ask a question? Why use `ByRef` to return the folders collection instead of a function? [/meta review]

Comment: @RubberDuck - It feels like the cleanest solution. If it is a function then it either takes the current collection as a parameter and returns the updated collection or it just returns a collection and extra code is needed to to add the values from that one to the overall collection.

Comment: Interesting choice, but fair enough. I see what you mean.